# What Music programs will sync my MP3 player, Sony walkman S?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync

I am looking for a good music player for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit that will sync metadata and my playlists to a Sony walkman S series MP3 player.

So far I have tried banshee, Rythmbox, and Clementine, no one will sync anything.

Update 9/18 7:32 PM est: I hav trid Play on linux with Windows Media Player 10 (Crashed) and Amarok (Sync 3 songs and quit on me.

Answer (score 0):

Banshee is my favorite music app. It can read from exiting tags in music files and offers native support for almost any music device. I highly recommend checking it out. You can look for it in the software center by simply searching 'banshee' without the quotes :D

Comment: As stated in the question, I have tried banshee but it will not sync the metadata, last time I did it erased all my music and put the same song on 743 times (The size of my collection)

Comment: Create a '.is_audio_player' file on the device for Banshee to see it. That helped me a long time ago with an old rio mp3 player. Are you able to see the disk mounted in ubuntu?

Comment: how would I go about creating that?